# LINQ To Entities INNER JOIN with COUNT

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to do replicate the following query in LINQ using the comprehension method. My SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(Post.Id), User.Id, User.Name
FROM Post  
INNER JOIN User ON Post.ModeratorId = User.Id
WHERE Post.Status IN ("Live", "Pending", "Expired")
GROUP BY User.Id, User.Name
```

My LINQ query is as follows but its still returns a 0 count when no moderator has been assigned to the post. Note a Post.ModeratorId is a nullable value.

I only want a list of moderators and a count of post they are or have moderated.
How can I replicate the above SQL in LINQ?

```
    public IEnumerable<ModeratorPostViewModel> GetModeratorPostCount()
    {
        var posts = _context.Post
                       .Include(p => p.Moderator)
                       .Include(p => p.Status)
                       .Where(p => p.ModeratorId != null && p.Status.Name IN ("Live", "Pending", "Expired"))
                       .OrderBy(p => p.Moderator.Name)
                       .Select(p => new ModeratorPostViewModel 
                       {
                           Id = p.ModeratorId,
                           Name = p.Moderator.Name,
                           CountOfPosts = p.Moderator.ModeratorPosts.Count()
                       })
                       .ToList();

        // Return list
        return posts 
    }
```

My models are defined as follows:

```
public class Post
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   int StatusId { get; set; }
   string ModeratorId { get; set; }

   // Navigation properties
   public Status Status { get; set; }
   public ApplicationUser Moderator { get; set; }

   // some other other properties
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public ICollection<Post> ModeratorPosts { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, but are you getting `0` for `CountOfPosts = p.Moderator.ModeratorPosts.Count()`? Or your query is returning `0` `posts`?

Comment: If it is that your `p.Moderator.ModeratorPosts.Count()` is 0? Try an `Include()` for this, as well as your other 2 - `.Include(p => p.Moderator.ModeratorPosts)`, as I guess this is a navigation property also

Comment: First off, you don't need `Include` (they are ignored) when projecting. Second, why don't you start your query from the table that contains moderators?

Comment: @Geoff yes the query is returning `0` for `CountOfPosts = p.Moderator.ModeratorPosts.Count()`. I've tried your suggestion above and I still get a 0 for CountOfPosts. If no moderator has been assigned the ticket then it should not return any values at all as per the SQL.

Comment: That's because the `.Count` function will return 0. What are you expecting it to return? As @IvanStoev has suggested, why don't you start your query from the moderator table? I'd just re-read your Linq query, and realised that you're only returning the list of ModeratorPostViewModels - for some reason, I thought you were returning a list of Posts - in this case, you won't need the `.Include()`s, as they're not being returned out of this query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I only want a list of moderators and a count of post they are or have moderated

Then base your query on `Moderator` (or whatever it's called) entity:

```
var statuses = new [] { "Live", "Pending", "Expired" };
var posts = _context.Moderator
    .OrderBy(m => m.Name)
    .Select(m => new ModeratorPostViewModel 
    {
        Id = m.Id,
        Name = m.Name,
        CountOfPosts = m.ModeratorPosts.Count(p => statuses.Contains(p.Status.Name))
    })
    .Where(m => m.CountOfPosts != 0)
    .ToList();
```

**UPDATE:** I have to admit that the above LINQ query does not produce a very good SQL, especially with the last `Where` condition. So you might resort to the exact LINQ equivalent of your SQL query (you missed the `GROUP BY` part):

```
var statuses = new [] { "Live", "Pending", "Expired" };
var posts = _context.Post
    .Where(p => p.ModeratorId != null && statuses.Contains(p.Status.Name))
    .GroupBy(p => new { Id = p.ModeratorId, Name = p.Moderator.Name })
    .Select(g => new ModeratorPostViewModel 
    {
        Id = g.Key.Id,
        Name = g.Key.Name,
        CountOfPosts = g.Count()
    })
    .OrderBy(m => m.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Good answer and 4 seconds faster with almost the exact same solution I was writing

Comment: The post update does not change the solution. Just change `_context.Moderator` to `_context.ApplicationUser` (or how it is called).

Comment: You may add a .Where clause after the Select to filter out items where CountOfPosts == 0

Comment: @Ivan your solution doesn't work. I get error on the line `Id = m.Id,`  becuase `m` doesnt not exist in the current context?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to rename one of the lambda variables after pasting and modifying your code. Also I'm not sure if the property is called `Id` (it's not visible from your model), so you may need to adjust it.

Comment: @Ivan Your solution doesn't work because its still giving me a list of moderators with a count of 0. I only want a list of moderators if they are moderating any posts other wise it should return an empty result set.

Comment: As per Tims suggestion I've added a where clause which seems to do the trick.

Comment: @Ivan I was almost there then with my original attempt. Thanks for your help though. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a group by after filtering the posts by the statuses you are looking for

```
var s = new List<string>() {"Live", "Pending", "Expired"};
var grouped = db.Post.Where(x => s.Contains(x.Status)) //Fitler for the statuses
                 .GroupBy(f => f.ModeratorId, po => po,
                              (k, items) => new ModeratorPostViewModel
                                            {
                                               Name = items.FirstOrDefault().User.Name,
                                               Id=k, 
                                               CountOfPosts = items.Count()
                                            }).ToList();
```